# Trivium and its register size

Tags: encryption

I am also wondering why the three registers in a Trivium were chosen to be of different lengths. Was there a reason behind the decision?

Bob

Comment: i believe that is outlined in the paper

Comment: **What research have you done?** I'm asking because sharing research efforts helps everyone! Tell us what research you did, what you found, and why it didn’t meet your needs. That shows users you took time trying to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and (most important) it helps you to get more relevant on-point answers. ***In case of doubt, you can start by reading the Trivium paper!*** At worst it will help you frame [*“a better question”*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); at best it might even answer it.